# Facebook Group chat using XMPP framework

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, xmppframework

I tried and now perfectly working facebook single chat, how far it is possible to create a facebook group chat in ios app using XMPP framework ? or any other frame works we have?

Comment: Can you please share your knowledge on Facebook single chat? I'm getting Authentication fail error. Thanks.

Comment: i used [this](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/tree/master/Xcode/Testing/FacebookTest)code.